# What is the purpose of the 3type man page section in the online man-pages project, and how can I install them locally?

Tags: linux, glibc, manpage

`man getaddrinfo` shows me documentation for the `getaddrinfo()` function without my having to search online.

The various structs defined in libc are equally useful to learn about but don't appear in my installation of the `manpages` package (PopOS jammy default repos). The online version of man-pages includes info about types in a `3type` section that I don't have. Example: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sockaddr.3type.html

Why would the `3type` section exist online but not seemingly in packaged version? Is there a way to install this documentation locally?

I tried searching my available repositories for another `manpages` package variation that included more things, but I couldn't find it. I also could not find an explanation of the `3type` section on the `man-pages` website: https://man7.org/ I see that `manpages-posix-dev` in some repos includes certain addition sections like `3posix` and `7posix`, but I don't see something similar for the `3type` section.

Comment: Maybe your installation is faulty. `man 3 sockaddr` works fine for me.